# Server execution failed while trying to run DCOM component with any other user than Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, openoffice.org, dcom

Afternoon,

As the topic says, I'm getting this error while trying to run a webapplication that uses a DCOM agent.

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {82154420-0FBF-11D4-8313-005004526AB4} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."

I've created a user solely to run this but I cannot get it running.

If I change "identity" in dcomcnfg.exe as well as the running user in the AppPool to Administrator it works instantly, but with the custom made user, not.

For troubleshooting purposes I've even added the user to the Administrators group, but it still won't run.

The component is OpenOffice 3.3 by the way, installed without QuickStart and with the Active-X support, and I'm trying to convert an .ODT to .PDF

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Regards LP

Comment: The DCOM server tries to perform some action that can't be performed under the account it starts under. One possible way to identify the problem is to use Process Monitor to see what that action might be. Once you know exactly you can think of how to solve it.

Comment: I have the same problem now...

Comment: **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.** For More information check this [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 2):

Had to make AbcPdf 9.125 work with OpenOffice 4.1.2 on a windows server 2012 R2 and ended up with the same problem. Took me a day to set it up correctly.

Despite DCOM configuration OpenOffice wouldn't launch with IIS Application Pool's virtual account.

ABCPDF: http://www.websupergoo.com/support-open-office-org.htm

Open Office and Virtual Account: http://mytestdata.blogspot.fr/2014/04/configure-open-office-for-virtual.html

Spying with process monitor would show a process hang until it reaches timeout.

To make it work :

- Copy OpenOffice user's settings from your interractive user to `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\`
- Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\bootstrap.ini` and change following line: `UserInstallation=File:///C:/Users/Default/AppData/Roaming/OpenOffice/4`
  (**mind the three slashed after File:**)

Hope it can help